# How to use only real values in a notebook?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, special-functions, notebooks, algebra

I am wondering how to make Mathematica only evaluate real numbers by creating an initialization line in the beginning of a notebook.
I would like to prevent the following:

- complex trigonometric functions
- complex matrices that are imaginary and not real
- graphs and plots of imaginary values, both 2d and 3d
- complex exponents and logarithms of negative numbers
- algebraic expressions such as x^2+1=0 so Solve returns an empty result
- special functions such as the error function as integration results

Is there a simple way to restrict a notebook object with a line of initialization code in order to return empty results such as {} or no solution found or out of domain error for cases such as arcsin(5)?
I am looking for something similar to Wolfram Alpha Notebook's edition option to solve only over Real values.
[image]